# When did 4 part writing allow 2nd inversion chords

Tags: counterpoint

In 4 part counterpoint in the strict old-fashined style, the 2nd inversion chord was not allowed but in todays compositions the 2nd inversion chord is a staple so when did this rule change and at what point did 2nd inversion chords become "allowed" by classical composers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the 2nd inversion chord allowed in 4 part counterpoint?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/111916/is-the-2nd-inversion-chord-allowed-in-4-part-counterpoint)

Comment: Close one or the other dup questions.

Comment: I closed the other one, wasn't aware it had actually gone live

Answer (score 1):

According to Glen Haydon "The Evolution of the Six-Four Chord," the 6-4 chord had become common by the early 1200s. He gives examples due to Perotín and Adam de la Halle. There are also comments implying that the earliest known Western music used 6-5 chords.

This chord had been used since "antiquity" (before we have good notation for the subject) but there were different rules pertaining to dissonance in general. Arppegia 6-4 chords don't ever seem to be a problem. The "cadential 6-4) does seem to occur fairly early with the usual dissonance preparation and resolution. Jeppesen's "Palestrina and the Dissonance" examines Palestrina's treatment of dissonance in various situations. (Haydon discusses use of the 6-4 chord by various composers.)